# Delete user in active directory using c#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I've written some code but not works it throws Exception "An operations error occurred."
code --->

```
DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP path", "admin-username", "admin-password");
dirEntry.Properties["member"].Remove("username-delete");
dirEntry.CommitChanges();
dirEntry.Close();
```

give me some ideas to get out of this things..

Comment: You're trying to remove a member from a group, it seems ...... what dose the "LDAP path" refer to? The user account you're trying to delete? Some container?

Comment: ye. i'm trying to remove a user account from CN=Users OU . but i cant ..

Comment: OK, that **what is in** the "LDAP Path" you're using there?? Do you have `CN=Users,DC=Yourcomapny,dc=com` in there?? Or the actual user account's LDAP path???

Comment: The user account isn't a **member** in the `CN=Users` OU - it's a child entity in there (users might be members of **groups** - but not of containers like `CN=Users`). You cannot delete it by removing it from the (non-existing) "member" property of `CN=Users`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find the user you want to delete
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

if(user != null)
{
   user.Delete();
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: @Ali: try this: `user.Enabled = false; user.Save();`

Comment: @Ali write new question about it

Comment: Since these are all IDisposable you should make sure you using a 'using' block or .Dispose()

Answer (score 3):

When you are already using a DirectoryEntry there is no need for PrincipalContext or UserPrincipal.

You can simply use the `DeleteTree()` method:

```
DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP path", "admin-username", "admin-password");
dirEntry.DeleteTree();
```