# Get Environment Variable values of all User Account

Tags: c#

I need to delete some folders inside special folders which I am doing like this

```
string dir = null;

dir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
dir = IO.Path.Combine(dir, "FOO\\BAR");
if (IO.Directory.Exists(dir))
    IO.Directory.Delete(dir, true);

dir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
dir = IO.Path.Combine(dir, "FOO\\BAR");
if (IO.Directory.Exists(dir))
    IO.Directory.Delete(dir, true);
```

but this only deletes folder of logged in user.

I want to delete same folders of all user accounts.

How to do that?

Comment: Would you not have to be the administrator to do this?

Comment: Have you seen this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426035/delete-user-in-active-directory-using-c-sharp/9426287#9426287

Comment: @KaushikKishore: I do not want to delete that user. Only some folders of its profile.

Comment: Perhaps you can queue a job, which will be executed when user login. Those folders are not going to be used anyway until that, right? Cheap solution is to have something in autorun for all users.